# SQL : how to select once 2 columns values in a result

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I have :

```
ID  USER1  USER2  TEXT
=======================
1   Toto    Roro  Text1
2   Toto    Riri  Text2
3   Tata    Roro  Text3
4   Titi    Rara  Text4
5   Tutu    Riri  Text5
```

I want :

```
ID  USER1   USER2  TEXT
=======================-
1   Toto    Roro  Text1
4   Titi    Rara  Text4
5   Tutu    Riri  Text5
```

I would like that USER1 and USER2 appear only once in my result, and order by id asc.

I could do a lot of distinct on with subquery but i think it is not optimized...

I wish also limited the number of resultat to 10 for example, because i have a lot of lines in my table.

I have something like that :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (user2) *
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (user1) *
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM
                test
            ORDER BY
                id ASC
            LIMIT 100
        ) as foo1
        ORDER BY user1, id ASC
        LIMIT 100
    ) as foo2
    ORDER BY user2, id ASC
    LIMIT 100
) as foo3
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Tata is attached to Roro which appears in the answers in line 1. I don't think he wants Roro to show up twice so Tata is skipped.

Comment: Don't come here to only ask us to provide you with a solution. Show us what you have you gotten so far as a query, and we might get more willing to help.

Comment: So how do you decide to skip Tata, instead of skipping Roro? Rows (2,3,4) would also be a valid set. This is starting to feel like a fairly complex set-covering problem.

Comment: Wumpus, yes, because i make my first filter on user1 order by id asc, so in a firs time i can filter on user 1 and after on user 2, but i don't know if i could do something lite with partition...

Comment: So you want a greedy algorithm that always adds the lowest-ID row that won't conflict. Do you realize this won't always maximize the size of the result set? You could construct a list where (1,4,5) works, but (2,3,4,6) also works, and if you just go by low ID with no backtracking you'll miss the bigger solution.

Comment: If I have 400 000 lines, i think that subqueries with distinct on could be too heavy...

Comment: Wumpus, we can imagine that we replace ID by date, i would like order by the oldest, so the first id. I am sorry for my bad english...

Comment: You just _happen_ to have three distinct values in each column.  What if one column has more distinct values that the other?

Comment: This query result that you're after makes very little sense.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: sarin, i use postgresql

Comment: Check my answer again. I was able to come back with "fresh eyes" and built the solution you were asking for in sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Select * from table t1
    Where not exists (select 1 from table t2
                      where t2.id<t1.id 
                      and (t1.user1 in (t2.user1, t2.user2) 
                          or t1.user2 in (t2.user1, t2.user2)
                          )
                      )
```

Had to edit on my laptop. I think this is what you mean. and you want to limit the number of results to 10 then just put top 10 in the select or did i misunderstand?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f543b/18 Your result set is still wrong. Your query doesn't include the id #5.

Comment: I think that "5   Tutu    Riri  Text5" will not in the result, because "2   Toto    Riri  Text2" will exclude the possibility to have Riri with your query.

Comment: Line 5 won't be excluded because the way the OP wants everything done, this would "create a list" as it moved down the items and by the time it got to line 5, Riri, which is on line 2, would have already been excluded.

Comment: I see what you mean, so I'll have a sub query, so at first, I'll filter on user1 and after in a subquery, filter user2. I think it will be heavy, but it seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f543b/148

```
select sj1.uid as uid,
sj1.u1 as u1,
sj2.u1 as u2,
j.text
from jargon as j

    ,(select j1.user1 as u1,
    j1.user2 as u2,
    min(j1.id) as uid,
    count(j1.user1)
    from jargon as j1
    group by j1.user1) as sj1

    ,(select j2.user2 as u1,
    count(j2.user2)
    from jargon as j2
    group by j2.user2) as sj2

where sj1.u2 = sj2.u1
and j.id = sj1.uid
group by sj2.u1
having min(sj1.uid)
order by sj1.uid asc
```

This returns rows 1, 4, 5 but with such a small set of data, I can't be certain that this will work for your entire set. I have a much larger query that would most likely work with the larger data set but it's fairly unoptimized.